# Drupal hook alter with hook validate

Tags: drupal, hook, validation, drupal-fapi, drupal-alter

I have a CCK defined form called 'mytype_node_form'.

I create a module called form_overrides

I create a function called form_overrides_form_alter where I successfully check for $form_id = 'mytype_node_form'

Question:

What should be the name of my validation function (hook_validate) in module form_overrides that would allow me to add custom validation to form mytype_node_form?

I thought it should look something like this

function form_overrides_mytype_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) or
function form_overrides_validate($form, &$form_state)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the validation function in `$form['#validate']`, then Drupal looks for a function named with the form ID plus "_validate". So in this case it would be looking for `mytype_node_form_validate()` (and similarly `mytype_node_form_submit()` for the submit function).